# Python regex named result with variable

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing code to parse SVG's `transform` command in Python3.7:

```py
t = "translate(44,22) rotate(55,6,7) scale(2)"
num = "[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?" 
types = "matrix|translate|rotate|scale|skewX|skewY"
regex = f"({types})\((?P<arg1>{num})(?:,?(?P<argi>{num}))*\)" # <- 'i' as an increasing number
matches = re.finditer(regex, t)
print(match.groupdict())
```

The `types` in input string `t` could have up to 6 parameters inside of the parentheses ('matrix' has 6, others have fewer). I'd like to use `groupdict()` to give me numbered arguments `arg-1`, `arg-2`, `arg-3`, etc. depending on how many `finditer` has found. That means that the named match needs to be a variable that's increasing.

I've tried some obvious stuff and looked at the docs. Neither got it working for me.

So... is it possible? Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Thanks!

Comment: Is this exactly how the string is constructed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there can only be up to 6 arguments inside the parentheses, use six `(?:,(?P<argX>{num}))?` optional groups (where `X` is a digit from 1 to 6) to match 1 to 6 patterns matching the arguments, and then discard all the groupdict items that have `None` value:

```
import re
t = "translate(44,22) rotate(55,6,7) scale(2)"
num = "[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?" 
types = "matrix|translate|rotate|scale|skewX|skewY"
regex = f"({types})\((?P<arg1>{num})(?:,(?P<arg2>{num}))?(?:,(?P<arg3>{num}))?(?:,(?P<arg4>{num}))?(?:,(?P<arg5>{num}))?(?:,(?P<arg6>{num}))?\)" # <- 'i' as an increasing number
for match in re.finditer(regex, t):
    print({k:v for k,v in match.groupdict().items() if v is not None})
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FiFbFE) yielding

```
{'arg1': '44', 'arg2': '22'}
{'arg1': '55', 'arg2': '6', 'arg3': '7'}
{'arg1': '2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `ast.literal_eval` with `re` to parse the parameters, for example:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

t = "translate(44,22) rotate(55,6,7) scale(2)"
types = "matrix|translate|rotate|scale|skewX|skewY"

print([(f, literal_eval('(' + s + ',)')) for f, s in re.findall(fr'({types})\(([^)]+)', t)])
```

Prints:

```
[('translate', (44, 22)), ('rotate', (55, 6, 7)), ('scale', (2,))]
```